# Call webservice in service file and re-use in other places

Tags: arrays, json, angular, api, web-services

I need assistance in re-using a service function in other parts of my app and more specifically display a certain parameter in the HTML template(in my case the 'title').

So basically I created a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserInfoService {

loading: boolean;
dataSet = [];

constructor(public http: HttpClient) { 

 this.getList();

}

getList(){
  this.loading = true;
  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.dataSet = [data];
  this.loading = false;
  });
}}
```

Then I have a component which imports the above service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInfoService } from '../../models/user-info.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-user',
 templateUrl: './user.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

 res = [];

constructor( private UserInfoServiceData:UserInfoService ) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.res = [this.UserInfoServiceData];

}}
```

Lastly in my HTML template I am trying to display the 'title' from the web service. Currently I am getting [object Object].

```
<p>
    <span *ngFor="let res of res">{{res | json}}</span>
</p>
```

Comment: res is your UserInfoService itselft. you must write this.res=this.UserInfoServiceData.dataSet

Comment: @Eliseo I done that  but it seems to give me a blank result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Observable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class UserInfoService {

loading: boolean;
private dataSetSource = new Subject<any | Error>();
public _dataSet:  Observable<any | Error> = this.dataSetSource.asObservable();


constructor(public http: HttpClient) { 

//try to not put things here if you can

}

getList() {
this.getHTTPList();
 return this._dataForm;
}

private getHTTPList(){
  this.loading = true;
  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.dataSetSource.next(data);
  this.loading = false;
  });
}}



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInfoService } from '../../models/user-info.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-user',
 templateUrl: './user.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

 res = [];

constructor( private UserInfoServiceData:UserInfoService ) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.UserInfoServiceData.getList().subscribe (
(data: any) => { 
this.res.push(data);
}
);

}}

<p>
    <span *ngFor="let var of res">{{var | json}}</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I take it there need to be more import statements for the observables(rxjs)

Comment: You're right, I've already fixed it. if it is the correct answer and you think it helps you remember to mark it as the correct one, so you also help others as well

Comment: OK, seems like subject also needs importing: import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';. That seems fine although there is an error on the subscribe part: this.UserInfoServiceData.subscribe (says subscribe does not exist on type 'userInfoService')

Comment: Yes i omit the funtion call, import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';. is there :). hopes it helps

Comment: thanks also just needed to declare the _dataForm variable